# Is there a way to get an OS error code from a std::io::Error?

Tags: error-handling, rust

When I run the following:

```rust
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let filename = "not_exists.txt";
    let reader = File::open(filename);

    match reader {
        Ok(_) => println!(" * file '{}' opened successfully.", filename),
        Err(e) => {
            println!("{:?}", &e);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }
```

Is it possible to get that code as an integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`io::Error::raw_os_error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.raw_os_error):

```rust
match reader {
    Ok(_) => println!(" * file '{}' opened successfully.", filename),
    Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e.raw_os_error()),
}
```

Output:

```
Some(2)
```

See also:

- [How does one get the error message as provided by the system without the "os error n" suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40710115/155423)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the [`raw_os_error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.raw_os_error) method on `std::io::Error`. Example:

```rust
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let filename = "not_exists.txt";
    let reader = File::open(filename);

    match reader {
        Ok(_) => println!(" * file '{}' opened successfully.", filename),
        Err(e) => {
            println!("{:?} {:?}", e, e.raw_os_error());
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0cb35351fced7c0746f25524a3992f2)